# Getting 2 errors while converting MP3 to WAV

Tags: python, mp3, wav, python-module, pyglet

I am trying to play mp3 file using pyglet module.
Following some suggestions, I have already installed avbin64 and moved avbin64.dll to the directory where my python code is. but still, I am getting 2 errors

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.resource.media('song.mp3')
music.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\codecs\wave.py", line 59, in __init__
    self._wave = wave.open(file)
  File "C:\Users\udit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wave.py", line 510, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Users\udit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wave.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Users\udit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wave.py", line 131, in initfp
    raise Error('file does not start with RIFF id')
wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PycharmProjects/test/test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    music = pyglet.resource.media('song.mp3')
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\resource.py", line 678, in media
    return media.load(path, streaming=streaming)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 143, in load
    raise first_exception
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 133, in load
    loaded_source = decoder.decode(file, filename, streaming)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\codecs\wave.py", line 109, in decode
    return WaveSource(filename, file)
  File "F:\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\codecs\wave.py", line 61, in __init__
    raise WAVEDecodeException(e)
pyglet.media.codecs.wave.WAVEDecodeException: file does not start with RIFF id
```

Answer (score 3):

As per ["Loading media"](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/programming_guide/media.html#loading-media), you're supposed to open audio (and video) files with `pyglet.media.load`:

```
music = pyglet.media.load('song.mp3')
```

You must also have ffmpeg installed for pyglet to be able to read mp3 files (as per [Supported media types](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/programming_guide/media.html#supported-media-types)). Make sure to follow the [installation instructions](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/programming_guide/media.html#ffmpeg-installation).

Comment: I have already installed FFmpeg and tried opening files with `pyglet.media.load` but still, I am getting the same error

Comment: @Anjali Did you follow the [installation instructions](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/programming_guide/media.html#ffmpeg-installation)?